Push .hyper file from python to Tableau Cloud?
As the title says, is it possible to push a .hyper file from python to tableau cloud? I can't seem to find any documentation on it. It looks like it was possible for tableau server.
My intent is to determine a workaround for the issue of not allowing embedded R and python scripts in tableau prep on tableau cloud. I had initially created a flow that utilized embedded R scripts and I would spin up a Rserve instance locally and the flow would run perfectly. However, I learned tableau cloud is not compatible with Rserve and tabpy due to uploading embedded scripts to their domain. My thought is I could run the script locally each morning at 8am through an event handler and have the .hyper file that is created be "pushed" to tableau cloud. My team has a tableau bridge directory however that seems to only allow xlsx files and my data is too large for xlsx.
Below is a snippet of converting the final_pairing data-frame from an R df to a python df then using pantab to save as a .hyper. Is it possible to directly push or save that to tableau cloud?
import pantab as pt
from tableauhyperapi import TableName



hyp = r.final_pairing

pt.frame_to_hyper(hyp, "Final_Pairing.hyper", table = "table")



